# Convert utc time to timezone time using an offset in minutes C#

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime, timezone, datetimeoffset

1. The frontend sends a timezoneOffsetInMinutes

```js
var timezoneOffsetInMinutes = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
console.log(timezoneOffsetInMinutes);
```

2. Api receives the offset

   ```
   public DateTimeOffset GetDateTimeOffsetAtTimezone(int timezoneOffsetInMinutes)
   {
       var utc = DateTime.UtcNow;
       utc.AddMinutes(timezoneOffsetInMinutes); //Apply the offset
       var result = new DateTimeOffset(utc, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(timezoneOffsetInMinutes)); //Set the offset

       return result;
   }
   ```

For some reason i get this error message

*`"The UTC Offset for Utc DateTime instances must be 0. (Parameter 'offset')"`*

I don't want to use NodaTime because I already have the timezoneOffset and i just need to apply it. Unless I am wrong about this and I should use NodaTime.

If you know the correct way of doing this that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question directly as asked:

```cs
public DateTimeOffset GetDateTimeOffsetAtTimezone(int timezoneOffsetInMinutes)
{
    // Start out with the current UTC time as a DateTimeOffset
    DateTimeOffset utc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

    // Get the offset as a TimeSpan
    TimeSpan offset = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(timezoneOffsetInMinutes);

    // Apply the offset to the UTC time to calculate the resulting DateTimeOffset
    DateTimeOffset result = utc.ToOffset(offset);

    return result;
}
```

That said - be sure you are only doing this when you are relaying the *current* time zone offset - the one that's valid *now* on the client, and *now* on the server (a reasonable transmission delay is acceptable).  To understand *why*, refer to to "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

If you also need to work with times *other than now*, then you'll need to instead gather the time zone ID from the client, not the offset.

```js
var timeZoneId = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;
console.log(timeZoneId);
```

That will return an IANA time zone identifier, such as `America/Los_Angeles`.

On the server side, you have choices:

- On a non-Windows system (Linux, OSX, etc.):

  ```cs
  public DateTimeOffset ConvertDateTimeOffsetToTimeZone(DateTimeOffset dto, string ianaTimeZoneId)
  {
      // Get the time zone by its identifier
      TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(ianaTimeZoneId);

      // Convert the input value to the time zone
      DateTimeOffset result = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dto, tz);

      return result;
  }
  ```
- On any OS (including Windows) using my [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) library:

  ```cs
  using TimeZoneConverter;

  public DateTimeOffset ConvertDateTimeOffsetToTimeZone(DateTimeOffset dto, string ianaTimeZoneId)
  {
      // Get the time zone by its identifier
      TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(ianaTimeZoneId);

      // Convert the input value to the time zone
      DateTimeOffset result = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dto, tz);

      return result;
  }
  ```
- On any OS (including Windows) using the [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org/) library:

  ```cs
  using NodaTime;

  public DateTimeOffset ConvertDateTimeOffsetToTimeZone(DateTimeOffset dto, string ianaTimeZoneId)
  {
      // Get the time zone by its identifier
      DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[ianaTimeZoneId];

      // Convert the input value to the time zone
      DateTimeOffset result = OffsetDateTime.FromDateTimeOffset(dto)
          .InZone(tz)
          .ToDateTimeOffset();

      return result;
  }
  ```

  *Of course, if you were using Noda Time throughout your project then you might prefer to keep things in terms of Noda Time's types rather than converting back and forth.*